# How to keep figure in focus, no matter what

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How do I keep a figure in focus of my system, even when I click on other things, outside of MATLAB? The idea is to 'pin a figure' on top, like an important forum post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [page](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/figure-window-customizations) illustrates how it can be done.

---

**An example**:

First, create the figure:

```
figure
f = gcf;
```

Then, use JavaFrame undocumented magic:

```
fJFrame = get(f,'JavaFrame');
jClient = fJFrame.fHG2Client;
jWindow = jClient.getWindow;
jWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

All credits to Yair Altman.

Comment: thank you I didn't find this googling. variable f is not needed

Comment: @user2305193 You are welcome. Indeed, it's for clarity. I just wanted to show how the existing handle of a figure could be used.